# django - How to create an object to be used in many views (for a dynamic menu)

Tags: python, django

I have a dynamic menu that i include in multiple templates. (sidebar.html)

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Service Menu</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{% url 'service:showrooms' %}">Showroom</a></li>
    {% for link in major_sites %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'service:majorsite' link.id %}">{{ link.location }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in my view i will get the data like

```
def index(request):
    model_urls =  MajorSiteInfoData.objects.only('location')

    return render(request, 'service/index.html', {
        'link': model_urls,
    })
```

But I have around 9 views in this app which all need this menu, How can I reuse the data as opposed to querying it 9 times for each view?

Thanks

Comment: You would normally use Django's caching mechanisms for this kind of things. Either cache the template fragment or the result of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `context_processors.py` in your app's directory. In there, create a function like

```
def add_sidebar_stuff(request):
    model_urls =  MajorSiteInfoData.objects.only('location')

    return {
        'link_urls': model_urls,
    }
```

And load it in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'my_app.context_processors.add_sidebar_stuff',
            ...
```

The above adds variables to every template context. That part may or may not be necessary, I don't know it you are already loading the variable elsewhere.

Then create a partial template `partial_menu.html`

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{% url 'service:showrooms' %}">Showroom</a></li>
{% for link in major_sites %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'service:majorsite' link_urls.id %}">{{ link_urls.location }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And where-ever you want to show it in your templates, `include` it.

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Service Menu</h3>
    {% include 'service/partial_menu.html' %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In django, you could use the concept of a context processor. Just write a function, which will be called on every request. It must return a dictionary of context you want to add, which in your case will be something like:

```
def menu_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'link': MajorSiteInfoData.objects.only('location')
    }
```

After adding this callable to the list of context processors in your `TEMPLATES` setting, every template rendered will now have `link` in its context (you might want to use a different name because of this). [django documentation on writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Alternatively, you could write a custom template tag to render this menu. [django documentation on writing custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/)